What is the significance of Jesus replacing ὁ θεός with ὁ κτίσας when citing Genesis?
Background
The creation of man is prefaced by God announcing the plan to make and create man.
Genesis 1:26a, 27 (ESV)

Then God said, “Let us make man in our image, after our likeness...
So God created man in his own image, in the image of God he created him; male and female he created them.

The plan has the verb, עָשָׂה, asa, to make;  the work, has a different verb, בָּרָא, bara, to create.
Genesis 1:26a, 27 (LXX)

And God (ὁ θεός) said, Let us make man according to our image and likeness...
And God (ὁ θεός) made man, according to the image of God (ὁ θεός) he made him, male and female he made them.

The LXX uses the same verb, ποιέω, to make, in both verses. In fact, the LXX does not use κτίζω in Genesis 1-2.
Matthew 19:4
When Pharisees questioned Jesus about whether divorce was lawful, He begins His reply by using Genesis 1:27.
Matthew 19:4 (DLNT)

And the One, having responded, said, “Did you not read [in Gen 1:27] that the One having created from the beginning ‘made them male and female’?
ὁ δὲ ἀποκριθεὶς εἶπεν οὐκ ἀνέγνωτε ὅτι ὁ κτίσας ἀπ᾽ ἀρχῆς ἄρσεν καὶ θῆλυ ἐποίησεν αὐτούς (MGNT)

Jesus uses two verbs, κτίζω, to create and ποιέω, to make. Since He is asking about reading Genesis, this suggests He is referring to the Hebrew Genesis. With both Hebrew and Greek in mind, a correct rendering of the Hebrew should use κτίζω, created them male and female. Jesus begins by using κτίζω but continues made them male and female, ἄρσεν καὶ θῆλυ ἐποίησεν αὐτούς which follows the LXX verbatim.
Regardless of Hebrew or Greek, God was the one who created/made; yet Jesus uses ὁ κτίσας not ὁ θεός, which follows neither the Hebrew or Greek.
What is the significance of Jesus replacing ὁ θεός with ὁ κτίσας when citing Genesis?

Cannot it be that He simply paraphrases a bit, for in the Biblical perspective of the audience He addressed the only κτίζων (creator) is and can be God. So, is the question why does He paraphrase a bit without change of meaning?

This is another perfect example of the NT authors, including Jesus who more often paraphrase the OT rather than quote it.

To clarify the possibility of Jesus using a Hebrew text we no longer possess (he translating, himself, into the lingua franca, Greek)someone might like to summarise for us the history of the Hebrew text prior to the Masoretic . . . . . . .

The simple answer to this question is: We do not know.  However, here are two possible explanations that are equally likely:

The Septuagint text is far from certain and at least several versions were circulating in Jesus' time.  Thus, there is no guarantee that the LXX text we have today is identical to what Jesus quoted.  Thus, it is quite possible that Jesus quoted correctly from the LXX text of His day.

It only takes a short glance at the numerous times that NT writers, including Jesus, quoted the LXX to discover that they rarely quoted it verbatim but often paraphrased it.  It is entirely possible that Jesus did exactly this in Matt 19:4 when quoting Gen 1.


Both these scenarios are equally likely.

I understand the point of paraphrasing when using Scripture, but even if that is the case in Matthew 19, is it appropriate to essentially dismiss what Jesus says? (see Luke 24) Also, is replacing ὁ θεός, which is not disputed in any LXX manuscript or in the Hebrew, really just paraphrasing?

@RevelationLad - the simple answer is, that we cannot be sure that the LXX text we have today is what Jesus was using.  Look at Romans and how often the NT paraphrases the OT.

I do not believe comparing Paul and Jesus is proper. Jesus was not consulting a manuscript when He spoke; even if He did, any changes He made to a Greek text would be a 100% accurate translation from Hebrew into Greek. Because of who He is, Jesus' use of Scripture is authoritative. His words represent a correct interpretation in Greek of the Hebrew.

@RevelationLad - ... and Paul's inspired text was not also reliable?  Recall that Jesus' words are only those reported by someone else (eg, Matthew, Mark, Luke & John) while Paul's words are direct.

I did not say not Paul was not reliable. I said there is a difference. There is a difference between Paul teaching Gentiles Scripture and Jesus questioning Pharisees about what they think they already know about Scripture.
